# Vertical Progress bar in iOS with Autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I am trying to make a vertical progress bar in iOS that can be placed as a UIView in interface builder, and given a progress bar view class. Here are my class files:

ProgressBar.h:

```
@interface ProgressBar : UIView
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *barView
-(void)setBarValue:(float)value;
@end
```

ProgressBar.m:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    id s = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (s) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return s;
}

-(void)setBarValue:(float)val {
    [self.barView setBackgroudnColor:TURQUOISE];
    CGRect frame = self.barView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.barview.frame.size.height * val;
    [self.barView setFrame:frame];
}
```

The only constraint I have on the '`barView`' inside the `ProgressBar` element is 'align bottom edges'. The setFrame method never seems to update the bar, and even at full height, the inner `self.barView` isn't the same height as the `ProgressBar` view. The properties are all correctly linked in the Storyboard.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `barView` is a view within the `ProgressView`, but I don't see where you create that subview and add it to your `ProgressView`. In terms of how to change the bar, it depends upon whether you're using autolayout or not, so please share your code that creates and configures this subview.

Comment: Hi @Rob - I create the subview in the Storyboard directly, and add a connection. I do use autolayout - I believe this is part of the problem, but Autolayout is necessary for the App

Comment: Most of us would have created the subview programmatically (it seems like the behavior/design of the bar should be an implementation detail of the `ProgressView`, not something you have to set up in IB everytime you want to use it), but that's up to you. But you definitely want to set up constraints for your view. See my answer, below.

Comment: Unrelated, but are you using ARC? We tend to use `weak` for IBOutlets, nowadays (the view is retained when added as a subview, and you don't have to retain it again). But if not using ARC, then do as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue is that, if using autolayout, you should add your constraints for this subview in IB, too. (I assume you already added constraints for the `ProgressView`.) And you should not change the `frame` of barView, but rather change its constraints and then call `setNeedsLayout`. The easiest way will be to add leading/trailing/top constraints of zero and then create a final height constraint. You can then add an `IBOutlet` for that height constraint. You can then programmatically set the `constant` of that constraint (and if you're going to use a multiplicative factor, it should be the product of this factor and the overall progress view, not a factor of the bar, itself), and then call `setNeedsLayout`.